# Bones are not moving in pose mode

Tags: bones, pose-mode, 2d

They are not even rotating . The bones stays at there position without any movement .I am doing this for 2D animation and not 3d if anyone could help it would be great.

https://pasteall.org/blend/f0dc519c38194cfa9a0b9bc415c9e819

Comment: maybe your armature is in Rest position (in the Object Data panel)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not

Comment: could you please share your file (armature only)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ok, I uploaded it or do i have to share it here?

Comment: pasteall will give you an URL.  Edit your question on add the URL to it.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Pose Options* panel, disable the *Affect Only Locations* option:

[image]